# Como descobrir a versão do ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express.js

Como faço para descobrir a versão instalada do ExpressJs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o comando [npm list](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls)

Para obter a versão do express `npm list express`

Para ver a versão dos pacotes instalados utilize no projeto `npm list` ou `npm list -g` para ver todos os pacotes instalados.

Comment: Obrigada! Até mais...